# IPhone SDK: Stuck on Two views apps

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, view, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create log in app.
In log in process I create a `UINavigationController` to do navigation.
After log in, I want to jump to a `UITabBarController` window.

Therefore I added a `UINavigationController *navigationController;`
and set it as a primary view.

And `UINavigationController *navigationController;` to handle stuffs after log in.

and I use

```
UITabBarController *aTabView = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabWindow" bundle:nil];
[self setTabController:aTabView];
[navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:[tabController view]];
```

to change to the content view.

However, it does not show the content of `TabWindow.xib`

Comment: Can you format the code?

In debugging, does it run through the process of creating and adding UITabBarController?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient.
Actually, I am new to here and I am finding a way to format my code.
I creates a UINavigationController first then UINavigationController.

And switch it in AppDelegate.m by following code.

TabWindowController *aTabView = [[TabWindowController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabView" bundle:nil];

[self setTabWindowController:aTabView];

[navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
 
[self.window addSubview:[tabWindowController view]];

Comment: Actually, I want to make a login page. After login, I navigate to a tab bar page. I can make it clearer. If you have any questions about my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a viewcontroller on itself for the login view, something that subclasses `UIViewController`

You can then initialize your app with a `UINavigationController` with the root view of a `UITabbarController`.
Once the view has appeared for the first time (you could just pick whenever you initialize the initial `UINavigationController`) do this line:

```
[navController presentModalViewController:[[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease] animated:YES];
```

and then when the user logs in do (in the LoginViewController class)

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And the viewcontroller will hide the nav controller and the tab bar initially but then allow it to be seen after the user logs in!